# for loop cycle showing always the last array value swift 3 after HTTP request

Tags: swift, asynchronous, httprequest, grand-central-dispatch

I already used another post to solver part of the problem,so now I am able to wait the end of the request. I made a http request with Almofire and parse the resulting JSON file. the code inside the myGroup.notify i think is correctly executed ater the request is completed (if I print allCards.count returns the correct value). Why if I put the for loop inside it is always showing the last card?

Thanks for any help

```
import UIKit
mport SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//variables Declaration
var allCard = [Card]()
let allCardsHTTP: String = "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards?mashape-key="

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

    //get HTTp request with Alamofire

    myGroup.enter()
    Alamofire.request(allCardsHTTP, method: .get).responseJSON {
         response in
         if response.result.isSuccess {
             let jsonCards : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
             print("success")
             self.updateJSONCards(json: jsonCards)
          }
        else {
             print("error")
         }
         myGroup.leave()
    }

    myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
         //Updte UI here
         print(self.allCard[10].name) //This is Working

         for card in self.allCard {
            if card.cardsSet == "Basic" {
                print(card.name)
            }
        } //For loop always showing last card ???


    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//MARK: - JSON Parsing


//Write the updateJSONCards method here:
func updateJSONCards(json: JSON) {
    //create the cards
     for (set, value) in json {
         var card = Card()
         card.cardsSet = set
         if json[set].count != 0 {
            for i in 0...json[set].count - 1 {
                card.name = json[set][i]["name"].stringValue
                allCard.append(card)
             }
         }
         else {
             print("The set \(set) has no cards")
         }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: What happens if you print outside the if statement?

Comment: It will always show last card because in for loop you have put print() in if condition, so put that print() outside if condition

Comment: If I print after the foor loop print(self.allCards.count) is working, it returns the right card number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the `Card` instance at the wrong place.

Before the inner repeat loop you are creating **one** instance and appending the **same** instance to the `allCard` array. If `Card` is a class (reference semantics) all occurrences of that instance contain the same data (the last loop item).

Put the two lines **in** the repeat loop.

```
//Write the updateJSONCards method here:
func updateJSONCards(json: JSON) {
    //create the cards
     for (set, value) in json {
         if !json[set].isEmpty {
            for i in 0..<json[set].count {
                let card = Card()
                card.cardsSet = set
                card.name = json[set][i]["name"].stringValue
                allCard.append(card)
             }
         }
         else {
             print("The set \(set) has no cards")
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: That is solving the problem, but why print(self.allCard[10].name) is working and is showing another card if I do not adjust the code like you suggested? Following your comment it should always show the same card

Comment: Is it showing another card? It shows the expected number of cards but the name is supposed to be always the same having one (reference type) instance.