# Month Array overwrites instead of appending a new value

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

In basic terms, this is what happens. 
The code appends as so:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Instead of:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345...
```

Any help?

In the below code I fill the object `tempmonth` with the values needed and append it to `month:[Month]`.

Trying to build a custom calendar app. I tried editing the array directly by using `month[no]` but it shows index out of range even if I use `month[0]`.

```
class Year{
    var month = [Month]()

    func getMonths(){
        let tempMonth = Month()

        //get current date
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)

        for no in 1...12{
            tempMonth.month_no = no
            components.day = 1
            components.month = no
            tempMonth.allDays.removeAll()

            //find the first day of the week 
            let mydate = NSCalendar.current.date(from: components)!
            let weekdaySample = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: mydate)

            tempMonth.firstWeekday = weekdaySample
            //set the total days
            tempMonth.collectDays(tempMonth.month_no,tempMonth.firstWeekday)

            //Fix here 
            month.append(tempMonth)
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of having 12 different months, I have 12 of the same December month.

Comment: Most probably, `Month` is a *class* (reference type) so that the same instance is mutated and appended repeatedly. In that case your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44412238/1187415.

Comment: Move `let tempMonth = Month()` to inside the loop.

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `NSCalendar`. Just use `Calendar`.

Comment: Another solution is to make `Month` a `struct` instead of a `class`. But even then, always create variables in the smallest possible scope it is needed.

Comment: @rmaddy i tried moving the tempMonth = Month() inside the loop it worked perfectly thank you soo much.