# Swift Append() method overwrite previous data

Tags: swift

I am learning iOS now. I have difficulties in using append() method. That method is overwriting previous data. Below is **my model file**

```
import Foundation
import EVReflection

class RequestItem: EVObject {
    var itemId: NSNumber?
    var requestedQty: Int?
    var name: String!

}
```

Here is my **viewController file**.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var requestItems: [RequestItem] = []
    var requestItem = RequestItem()


    func setUpData() {
        for i in 1...10 {


            if  i < 3  {

                requestItem.itemId = i as NSNumber
                requestItem.requestedQty = 10
                requestItem.name = "Item name \(i)"


                self.requestItems.append(requestItem)

                print("--------------------------------------------Start--------------------------------------------")
                print( requestItems )
                print("--------------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------")
            }

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpData()

    }


}
```

The result that I get is below

```
--------------------------------------------Start--------------------------------------------
[RequestItem = {
  "requestedQty" : 10,
  "name" : "Item name 1",
  "itemId" : 1
}]
--------------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------Start--------------------------------------------
[RequestItem = {
  "requestedQty" : 10,
  "name" : "Item name 2",
  "itemId" : 2
}, RequestItem = {
  "requestedQty" : 10,
  "name" : "Item name 2",
  "itemId" : 2
}]
--------------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------
```

And the result that I would like to get is like below

```
--------------------------------------------Start--------------------------------------------
[RequestItem = {
  "requestedQty" : 10,
  "name" : "Item name 1",
  "itemId" : 1
}]
--------------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------Start--------------------------------------------
[RequestItem = {
  "requestedQty" : 10,
  "name" : "Item name 1",
  "itemId" : 1
}, RequestItem = {
  "requestedQty" : 10,
  "name" : "Item name 2",
  "itemId" : 2
}]
--------------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------
```

My question is ** why is *itemId* duplicating? How should I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RequestItem` is reference type and you are using always the (reference to the) same item.

Create a new instance **inside** the loop

```
var requestItems: [RequestItem] = []

func setUpData() {
    for i in 1...10 {
        if  i < 3  {
            let requestItem = RequestItem()
            requestItem.itemId = i as NSNumber
            requestItem.requestedQty = 10
            requestItem.name = "Item name \(i)"

            self.requestItems.append(requestItem)

            print("--------------------------------------------Start--------------------------------------------")
            print( requestItems )
            print("--------------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! I see the point. Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked and answered *many* times (e.g. by you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44412695/1187415)

Answer (score 1):

You have created only one instance of the `RequestItem` . When you loop first time it will set values to the instance as 1 . then you loop again the same instance get changed as the class is refernce type object.

Solution is you need to create a new instance of  `RequestItem` every time when the loop works .